# Sum question? Sum from $\infty$ to $\aleph_0$

Tags: infinity

$\sum^{\aleph_0}_{\mu=\infty}\mu=\aleph_0$? If this is true, however, then $\sum^{\aleph_0}_{\mu=0}\mu=\aleph_1$?

Comment: How are you defining your sums?

Comment: Neither question makes any sense . . .

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the expressions $\sum_{\mu=\infty}^{\aleph_0} \mu$ and $\sum_{\mu=0}^{\aleph_0} \mu$ don't have definitions. If an expression hasn't been defined, then it doesn't have a value.

In general, there's no definition of a summation that has $\aleph_0$ as one of its bounds.

Comment: Actually there is, but it's usually cardinal summation, and so the first one with bound $\infty$ doesn't make sense, however, as a cardinal sum, $\displaystyle\sum_{\mu<\aleph_0}\mu = \aleph_0$

Comment: @Max Actually that makes sense even as an *ordinal* sum, as long as the index set over which we're summing is well-ordered.

Comment: @Noah : yep I understood what you meant afterwards and thus deleted my comment